# Discourse bluepill to use rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rbenv, discourse, bluepill

In official discourse repository there's a [discourse.pill](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/config/discourse.pill.sample) file for [bluepill gem](https://github.com/bluepill-rb/bluepill) and it uses rvm.

Because I'm using rbenv I need that script to use rbenv (and I'm bad at environment stuff).

How I can convert this script, probably only this snippet of code?

```
bootup_bundle = [ "#{ENV['HOME']}/.rvm/bin/rvm/bootup_bundle",
                  "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm/bootup_bundle",
                  `which bootup_bundle`.strip,
                ].each do |location|
  if File.exist? location
    break location
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

We have come to hate bluepill and recommend running your Discourse instance using the [docker images](https://github.com/SamSaffron/discourse_docker).